# Android -- Changing Tab Visibility from Inside Tab Activities

Tags: android, tabs, visibility, switch-statement

I'm currently attempting to change tabs from inside of other activities -- that much is straight forward. However, I'm having trouble when attempting to set the visibility of other tabs.

Essentially, I have an application load to a tab (login page) and the other tabs are invisible until the user logs in.

When the user logs in, I want to make the other tabs visible and the login tab invisible.

If there is a simple way of doing this, please make me aware of it--I'm currently running around in circles:

Code Snippets:

In the TabHost's OnCreate:

```
.....

tabHost.setCurrentTab(3);

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setVisibility(View.GONE);

....
```

The TabHost's Extra Methods:

```
public void switchTab(int tab){
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
}

public void visibleTabs(){
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

public void invisibleTabs(){

    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

The Tab Activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {



EditText txt_username;
EditText txt_password;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



   setContentView(R.layout.login);


    Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    final EditText txt_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
    final EditText txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String username = txt_username.getText().toString();
            String password = txt_password.getText().toString(); 

            switchTabInActivity(0);

        }
    });


}

public void switchTabInActivity(long indexTabToSwitchTo){

    waiter ParentActivity = (waiter) this.getParent();
    ParentActivity.visibleTabs();
    ParentActivity.switchTab(0);

}


}
```

LogCat is As Follows:

```
04-12 19:37:49.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-12 19:37:49.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2744): java.lang.NullPointerException

04-12 19:37:49.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2744):     at android.waiter.waiter.visibleTabs(waiter.java:130)

04-12 19:37:49.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2744):     at android.waiter.LoginActivity.switchTabInActivity(LoginActivity.java:56)

04-12 19:37:49.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2744):     at android.waiter.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:44)
```

Its obvious that the exception is coming from the invisible/visible settings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0)` is the right way to do it. Have you tried giving the tabs an individual ID?

alternatively, if you want to try and track the exact location of the error throw a bunch of breakpoints and run it in Debug mode.

Oh `Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.login_button);` I believe can do without a "this" (although I could be wrong.... fwiw i never used `this` in a button declaration)

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Rasman, I figured out the problem! I just had to  declare tabHost in the tabHost in the TabHost's two custom methods. That solved the problem.